# Mobile HotSpot:802.11 to Cellular data conversion

Tags: wifi, ipv6, ipv4, cellular-network, tethering

I am trying to understand the mobile hotspot technology (tethering). Specifically, I am interested in how the devices connected to a HotSpot (via Wi-Fi) access the internet via Cellular network. Here are the specific questions :

1. I am assuming that internet access over cellular network (say 4G) is accomplished through IPv4 or IPv6 packets. Is this true?
2. If 1 is true, then how are 802.11 packets translated to form IPv4 or IPv6 packets?
3. If 1 is false, then which frames are used to access internet over cellular networks? and how are the 802.11 frames translated to form the these packets (cellular data)?

I did read the specification documents available for IPv4, IPv6 and 802.11 but they do not mention this particular (WLAN<->Cellular Data) conversion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- Please
- Do
- Not
- Throw
- Sausage
- Pizza
- Away

[Further reading.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)

802.11 packets are not *translated* into IP packets, or vice versa. IP packets (layer 3) are *encapsulated* in Ethernet and 802.11 (layer 2, layer 1) packets.

It is very hard to explain this any further until you have even the most basic grasp of network layers (which you don't have at the moment).